# Why am I geting a LinkDemand warning whenI'm just setting a control's property in form's constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple WinForms solution, with a Form that has a PropertyGrid in it. In Form's constructor, I set that propertyGrid's selected object:

```
    public FormSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pgMisc.SelectedObject = Settings.Current;
    }
```

And I'm getting this warning by Code Analysis:

> Warning   1   CA2122 : Microsoft.Security : 'FormSettings.FormSettings()'
>   calls into 'PropertyGrid.SelectedObject.set(object)' which has a
>   LinkDemand. By making this call,
>   'PropertyGrid.SelectedObject.set(object)' is indirectly exposed to
>   user code. Review the following call stack that might expose a way to
>   circumvent security protection:     ->'FormSettings.FormSettings()'
>   ->'FormSettings.FormSettings()'

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to disable this warning if there's nothing I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091162/do-i-need-to-worry-about-link-demands-in-a-full-trust-only-exe

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182303.aspx

Comment: I don't get it. Setting control's property in form's constructor is unsafe? How do I set it then? In a run-once timer event or something?

Comment: Pretty important to understand what FxCop does.  It rubs your nose into very obscure details that programmers overlook all the time.  Like this one, it is a way for untrusted code to get a reference to your Settings class.  What you do about it is first determine if it matters.  Do you conduct security reviews on your code?  Do you *actually* ever let untrusted code run in your Winforms program?  Important details that FxCop isn't smart enough to figure out by itself.  The 99% answer to either of those questions is "no".  So you say "thank you for reminding me" and turn the warning off.

Comment: Okay, I see. But, just out of curiosity, what is the safe way to set object property in a constructor then?